# HostListener 'scroll' event not firing, but 'mouseenter' event works ok

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple Stackblitz with a custom component ("ImagePicker"). This component has the overflow property set so the content causes it to scroll.

I am using a @HostListener to try and capture the `scroll` event but for some reason it is not working. I have also created a `mouseenter` event and this does indeed work just fine.

Why does the scroll not work?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/imagepicker

Comment: If you do `<div class="imagepicker" (scroll)="onScroll()">`, it works, I am not sure why that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You would expect a scroll event to bubble up, but it only does that when the `document` is scrolling. Which means you can capture scroll events on the `window` object, when the `document` scrolls.

Any other scroll events do not bubble up, and should be handled on the element actually scrolling. In your case, as @AliF50 stated, you have to put the listener on the div inside the image picker:

```
<div class="imagepicker" (scroll)="onScroll()">
```

The reason for this is to avoid performance issues, because scroll events can fire at a high rate. For instance when using smooth scrolling.

From the [W3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#scrolling-events)

> For each item target in doc’s pending scroll event targets, in the order they were added to the list, run these substeps:
>
> If target is a Document, fire an event named scroll that bubbles at target.
>
> Otherwise, fire an event named scroll at target.

Answer (score 0):

For making the scroll event work, the hostBinding package and the event is mentioned wrong. Please follow this code

```
import { Component, HostListener, HostBinding } from "@angular/core";



  @HostListener("window:scroll", ["$event"])
  onScrollEvent($event) {
    console.log("blah");
    this.eventData = $event;
  }
```

Choose the correct hostlistener and event name to make it work.

Comment: I've edited the code to use the `window:scroll` event and it still doesn't fire.

Comment: make this change as well

`import { Component, HostListener, HostBinding } from "@angular/core";`

Comment: Also change 

`onScroll` to `onScrollEvent`